# Updating python3-ldb

Tags: apt

I am trying to upgrade and there is an update for python3-ldb bindings which is never getting fully downloaded. Here I have tried

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

And then I get a confirmation message asking if it should download a certain amount of updates. I press Y to confirm.

Then it starts downloading the file, and then about halfway through, decides to "download" it again, i.e. it shows 3% done, 27%, 88% and then back to 3%, and never downloads fully.

I'm facing the same issue even when doing this from the Package Manager (GUI).

Thanks for any help.

I'm attaching a picture.[image: how it looks]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: I think it was self explanatory without that but I put it in case it helps...

Comment: Something is wrong with the internet connection.

Comment: I can use "heavier" things such as YouTube without any issues. The connection is one with a Firewall, do you think there is any reason this update could be blocked?